# Using Javascript to resize browser window in IE8. Explanation mostly

Tags: javascript

I have seen many examples on using javascript to resize a browser window, but for me they all fail to perform that function in IE.  I include my code to see if anything is wrong with it that I just don't see.  The code works great in FF but that is not used at my location.

I am no javaScript expert, but I am no slouch either.  If I were new to javaScript I would be hating it.  I'm sure it has something to do with IE but I cannot explain it.

Any help would be great.

CODE:

```
  //window.sizeToContent();
  window.resizeTo(700, 700);
```

I read in the docs that sizeToContent will not work in IE but resize should.  It is an incredibly simple statement.

Comment: Check out the MSDN article about this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536723(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Many browsers have the option to not allow scripts to resize windows, because it's one of those features that have been abused. I'm not sure IE8 specifically has this option (or generally doesn't allow resizing), but it's something you should consider.

Comment: Please don't do that, it's a pain for visitors to have their window resized, especially when having multiple tabs opened... Although (in firefox at least) one can prevent it in the browser options

Comment: Thanks all for the responses.  I just changed the initial window.open attributes to make the window the size I needed.  Here is the issue I was trying to solve.

0) user clicks a button.
1) open new window (modal w/sizes)
2) load jsp
3) depending on the loaded rec. the page size is variable.
4) if 3 increase the window size.
5) all this occurred during initial load.
@Šime - very true.  I needed the onload resize.
@Tim - Since the resize was wanted on the onload it would be unnoticed, hopefully
@Francisco – As I have outlined I am doing just as you say
Thank you all for your assistance. tnx IE

Comment: @GôTô - You are correct about resizing an existing window.  I was looking for and answer for it not working.  My window to be resized was a newly opened window.  A small detail that would have releived your concern.

Comment: @Travis Culbreth: ok, then you can just set the size when you open your window with window.open (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Internet explorer 8

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Resized</h1>

<script>
  window.resizeTo(400,400);
</script>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing in IE9 beta (that's the only version of IE that I have on this machine), and it seems that window.resizeTo does not work on the initial page load. It does work if you refresh the page. Also, it does work if you delay its execution:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.resizeTo(200, 200);
}, 2000);
```

(at least in IE9 beta)

Answer (score 1):

The "working" example with IE is working only because there are no more tabs on the window.

If the windows has other tabs loaded, then it DOES NOT work. It's a security measure of IE8 and higher.

If you need to resize your window, you will need to open a new window. And for that, you will need to make the user click a button with the window.open onclick event, otherwise any popup blocker will block it.

Comment: – Thanks, As I have outlined above, I am doing just as you say, but after the page with data is loaded the window will not resize.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to resize the window reliably with JavaScript. It's not possible in IE 7 with tabbed browsing enabled. It's also potentially annoying for the user.

Comment: @Henrik: How is it not an answer? I'm saying you can't do it in IE 7, which is popular enough not to be ignored, so in general it can't be done. Coupled with the fact that if you resize the window without the user triggering the action then it's going to be annoying, that adds up to good reasons not to even attempt it.

Comment: thanks. since the resize was wanted on the onload (or during the open window) the resize was hoped to be un-noticed. (see commens above)

Answer (score 0):

*This seems to be IE only.*

If your window is a "dialog" like:

```
window.showModalDialog(url,...)
```

I found this hacky way to make it the right size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //window.resizeTo(1000, 790); //Will not work if its a dialog
    window.dialogWidth = '1000px';
    window.dialogHeight = '790px';
</script>
```